# Multiplying a SQLite3 SELECT result with another value and inserting this result into another field

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I am currently working on a school project. I am trying to create an order form where the user will input a ProductID and quantity. From there, the price is selected from a seperate product table through the ProductID and multiplied by the quantity. The result is inserted into the price field on the Order table. Does anyone know of an easy way of accomplishing this? See screenshots of the UI and a snippet of the code I have so far below. Please let me know if you need any more information. I'm new to StackOverflow and coding.

```
    def SearchOrder(self):
        orderid = self.OrderIDEntry.get()
        productid = self.ProductIDEntry.get()
        quantity = int(self.QuantityEntry.get())
        with sqlite3.connect("LeeOpt.db") as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            price = ('''SELECT Price FROM Products WHERE ProductID = ?''')
            cursor.execute(price, [(productid)])
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            if results:
                for i in results:
```

[image: Order Form]

Comment: Give us an example of `results` and how you expect your _"multiplied"_ result to be.

Comment: Does it mean that you don't know how to insert the price into sqlite3 table?